# Preg_match PHP -- pattern matching

Tags: php, preg-match

trying to understand preg_match, struggling to understand how to write and how to access what it has matched. For example:

Every single movie name I have is in the format--

MOVIE NAME (YEAR)

e.g. Alice in Wonderland (2010)

I want to be able to get the movie title into a different variable from the string.

A few movies have parentheses outside of the year -- as in, The movie (Has One of These) (2008)

I'm iterating over an array of strings as well -- so I basically need to use preg_match to get to  `\([0-9]{4}\)$`  (is `$` the mark of an end of the line?) and then the rest of the string without that year as well in two variables.

Can anyone possibly help?

EDIT: Huh. I swear I typed \ . When I type \( it went into ( because I didn't double escape. Anyway, thank you guys very much! The site you linked it also awesome (helped with array problems, I didn't realize it kept full string at 0 as well).

Comment: It seems like you're almost there. What is the problem you're having exactly, though? What do you want help with exactly?

Comment: I guess I really don't understand how to skip over everything at the beginning in terms of regex terms

Comment: Well, you kind of have with the regex you used - the only difference is that you'd need to escape the ()s. ie: \([0-9]{4}\)$ should match the (nnnn) year at the end of a movie title.

Comment: @Paul did any of the answers helped you, if so. upvote them and check as correct the answer you think was more helpful.

Comment: I am unable to because i have 14, not 15 reputation...

Comment: @Paul glad I could help, now you have 16 :) congrats

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well if your pattern is: SOMETHING + (YEAR) then your regex should be like this:

```
 #^(.+)\((\d{4})\)$#
```

Explanation:

```
 # -> pattern delimiter
 ^ -> beginning of string
 (.+) -> any character "." once or more "+"
 \( -> escape parenthesis character
 \d{4} -> four digits
 \) -> escape parenthesis character
 $ -> end of string
```

[Example](http://xrg.es/#ubtoqf)

Answer (score 1):

Looking for patterns in these lines:

```
Alice in Wonderland (2010)
The movie (Has One of These) (2008)
```

You suggested in your question to use the following regular expression:

```
([0-9]{4})$
```

to match the year at the end of the line. `$` is infact a marker for the end of the line, however, the `)` is a special character in a regular expression that needs to be slashed to work:

```
\(([0-9]{4})\)$
  ^         ^^ both brackets have been slashed to match them literally
  '- subgroup parenthesis.
```

or by using `\d` for any decimal number:

```
\((\d{4})\)$
```

This will make subgroup 1 contain the year.

Answer (score 0):

[This is one of the link where `regex` man be made](http://public.kvalley.com/regex/regex.asp)

You also can use following for decimal number

```
\((\d{4})\)$
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an online regexp tester, it is very useful when learning regular expressions and testing them: [HiFi Regex Tester](http://www.gethifi.com/regexp).